Can i do floor wise explosion in autodesk forge viewer by using lockExplode(dbids, lock, model)
main.js
async function getFilteredDbIds(viewer, model) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
model.search('Ifc', dbIds => {
const filteredDbIds = dbIds.filter(dbId => {
return !viewer.model.getData().instanceTree.getNodeName(dbId).startsWith('Ifc');
});
resolve(filteredDbIds);
}, reject);
});
}

function lockExplodeNodes(viewer, dbIds, lock, model) {
return viewer.lockExplode(dbIds, lock, model);
}

async function applySelectiveExplode(viewer, model, scale) {
try {
const dbIds = await getFilteredDbIds(viewer, model);
lockExplodeNodes(viewer, dbIds, true, model);
viewer.impl.explode(scale);
} catch (error) {
console.error('Error applying selective explode:', error);
}

}

viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables,
loadOptions
)
.then((model)=>{
document.getElementById("explodeSlider").addEventListener("input", function() {
const scale = parseInt(this.value) / 100;
applySelectiveExplode(viewer, model, scale);
});
});

index.html
<input id="explodeSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />

see the image here how the model exploding floor wise

presemt my viewer image

present my viewer not exploding anything because i have written lockExplode .so in the model tree hierarchy the model elements are coming so i want to lockExplode for elements that coming in the levels.I want to explode the levels not the elements in it.How can i do that.In the above modle tree hierarchy image IFCBUILDING is coming inside that BASEMENT ,GROUND etc are coming.so how can i lockExplode for the elements inside the levels.

It's possible and has been explained in this blog
